# The nearest __sync_* alternative to acquire/release semantics?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, g++, lock-free

I'm porting some C++ code to an earlier version of g++ which does not support atomic types (~g++ 4.2)

In my C++11 code, I would use acquire/release semantics to store atomic variables

```
atomic<int> a;
...
a.load(memory_order_acquire);
// Some operations on 'a'
a.store(new_val, memory_order_release);
```

Which __sync_* builtin would be the best replacement to the load/store option?
I was thinking about using __sync_lock_test_and_set for the store, and __sync_lock_release for load, would this be sufficient?

Somewhat along the lines:

```
__sync_lock_release(a)
// Some ops on 'a'
__sync_lock_test_and_set(a,new_value);
```

(I'm trying to solve this **without locks**, if possible)

Comment: Yes,you can.And your program is not cross-platform.

Comment: I suggest you add the label for multithreading issues, lock-free programming

Comment: Not cross-platform, as in limited to G++? Or will it fail on some systems?

Comment: I guess,I guess code depends on the hardware or operating system.Wait answer with you.